# How to useTexture with blob on react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I want to place static background on scene. The background context stores the image uploaded by the user through the drop zone.

```
const BackgroundImage = () => {
  const { background } = useContext(MainContext);
  const texture = useTexture(background);
  return <primitive attach="background" object={texture} />;
};
```

This code throws an error:

**Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Could not load : undefined)**

I hope that someone know how to correct that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution with useLoader

```
const BackgroundImage = ({ background }) => {
  const texture = useLoader(
    TextureLoader,
    background
  );
  return <primitive attach="background" object={texture} />;
};
```